# Vim - indent like Emacs

Tags: vim, emacs, indentation

I use vim (primary so that I can work on plain ssh terminal - still uncomfortable with Emacs non-gui version) but most of my colleagues in the organization use emacs. So using CVS, we face indentation inconsistency issues (tabs becoming spaces, number of tabs/spaces, code layout etc).

Is there a way I can make VIM indent EXACTLY as EMACS. (similar to the default emacs profile my colleagues use).

(Most importantly, I want vim's C++ and TCL indentation schemes to match that of emacs).

regards,

JP

Comment: You could always try the [emacs vim mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VimMode)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way to directly import Emacs indentation settings into vim, but you can probably configure the same behavior in vim itself:

`set expandtab` will convert tabs to spaces
`set autoindent` will keep indentation level from previous line
`set shiftwidth=4` will affect block indentation with >> and <<
`set softtabstop=4` sets the length of soft tab in spaces
`set tabstop=8` sets the width of tab character

This is properly explained in [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code).

When you need filetype-specific indentation you have two options:

1. Set autocmd to change indentation on file read and file creation:
   `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*pyw,*.html,*.js set shiftwidth=4` will set shiftwidth for *.py files.
2. Configure filetype plugin, create `name.vim` scripts inside `.vim/ftplugin` folder for specific file types and set the described variables there. This is also described in proper detail in [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding specialized indenting for c++ and TCL there is some special stuff that applies in aditon to all the other setting info that's been suggested.  Vim has special indenting rules defined in code for different languages.  Some of this is found is found in the /indent directory of the vim installation, where there is a separate file for each filetype.  For more information on how this works read the help for 'indentexpr'.

The c indenting -- and I think also the indenting for c++ -- is mostly defined in Vim source-code, and has a zillion options that you can set, plus is specially configurable in c.vim or c++.vim indent file.  Read help for 'cindent' and 'c-indenting' for more help on that.

In short, the tcl.vim file controls special indenting for tcl files.  If you want to revise how indenting works with tcl you would want to alter the main function in that file.  The c/c++ indenting is largely controlled by Vim internals but with lots of different option flags.  You can control c/c++ indenting by configuring the options the way you want them and/or by writing a function for the indent file in /indent directory.  (I believe there is no c++ file in /indent directory, not sure if c.vim is file to edit there, or whether you need to create new c++.vim file.  I think it's the c.vim file that would be used. which is basically an empty shell in standard Vim install, but you can read other *.vim indent files to get the idea of how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's as extract of some options concerning indentation from .vimrc:

```
set expandtab
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set autoindent
set smartindent
```

All options are nicely described in vim help:

```
:help smartindent
:help autoindent
```

**UPD:** also for C-like languages you may consider `:help C-indenting`

Comment: Hi, Is there a way to know what value of tabstop/shiftwidth will mimic emacs most closely. bzh lists them as 8,4 however I suspect 2,2 are more appropriate. Any pointers?

Comment: @JP19 Sorry I've never used emacs so I don't know anything about the default look :)